# Non Editable UITextView automatically to scroll to bottom - without jumping from top to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I have a UITextView which is **non-editable**.

It simply receives a message from another device.

When the messages received fill the UITextView, it doesn't scroll down as new messages are received.

I have tried many solutions found on stack overflow but am unable to find anything that scrolls to the bottom, **without first scrolling** to the top and then to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in **viewDidAppear** :

```
[textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textView.contentSize.height - textView.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Basically textview contains scrollview so we can call scrollview methods.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Your code unfortunately still makes the textview scroll to the top before scrolling to the bottom. even with animated:NO.

Comment: You want that when view appear TextView will default scrolledToBottom Right?

Comment: Please check out this code... It's Working perfectly.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byb4VeRBzTKvNTUwcXUyeDBnSDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This loads the text at the bottom, on launch, but when more text is added, it doesn't keep scrolling the view to the bottom, view will keep jumping to top and then scrolling down.

Comment: Whenever new text is added to your textview you can recall the method .. i guess.